Getting jank issue while scrolling thousand of records in listview builder
There is pagination for that view but when I'm selecting to see 1000 records in a one page,
there is jank while scrolling.
I have listview builder for that ,is there any approach in which show table data have 1000 rows
and there is no lag while scrolling

If all children in the ListView have the same height consider putting an itemExtent on the ListView (or itemExtentBuilder when heights are not the same), with this you are telling it what height the children are, and this will significantly improve the performance of it.
ListView.builder(
  itemExtent: 50, //for example
  ...
)

Also, you should keep in mind that a ListView's performance is noticably worse in debug mode compared to release mode. So best to verify the true performance in release mode
